# CLKComplicationServer initializes an already initialized singleton class CLKComplicationDataSource, although init() is private

Tags: swift, singleton, watchos-3, apple-watch-complication

To update complications on the watch, I use a singleton class `ComplicationController` (irrelevant code has been omitted below):

```
final class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {

    static let shared = ComplicationController() // Instantiate the singleton

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        print("====self: \(self): init")
    } // Others can't init the singleton
}
```

The singleton is created on the watch by the extension delegate:

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

  override init() {
    super.init()
        _ = ComplicationController.shared           
  }
}
```

When I launch the watch extension with a breakpoint at the print statement above, the execution breaks and the stack trace is:
[image]

When I then execute the print statement in a single step, the debugger shows:

```
====self: <Watch_Extension.ComplicationController: 0x7bf35f20>: init
```

When I then continue, the execution breaks again at the same breakpoint, and the stack trace is:
[image]

After another single step, the debugger shows:

```
====self: <Watch_Extension.ComplicationController: 0x7d3211d0>: init
```

Obviously, the `CLKComplicationServer` has created another instance of the singleton.

**My question is**: Did I something wrong or is this a bug? If it is a bug, is there a workaround?

PS: It does not help **not** to initialize `ComplicationController` in the `ExtensionDelegate`. In this case, the 2nd instance is created as soon as `ComplicationController.shared` is used anywhere in the code.

Comment: I did some testing myself and got the same results, two instances of the singleton are created. However, I was experimenting with printing `self` from inside an instance method of `ComplicatonController`, `func doSomething(){  print("Function called on singleton"); print(self)}` and even if I call this function twice, from `ExtensionDelegate` and `InterfaceController`, both times it printed the same memory address for self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

**Do not instantiate the singleton in the app, i.e. do not use `ComplicationController.shared`  anywhere.**
If you have to call functions in `ComplicationController.shared`, send a notification, e.g. to the default notification center.
The `ComplicationController` singleton had to have registered for such notifications, and when it receives one, it has to execute the required function.
This did work for me.