# activeComplications of the CLKComplicationServer are nil, although a complication is displayed

Tags: watchos, apple-watch-complication

I have a watch app with complications. Updating the complication on a watch face did work for a long time, but stopped recently, maybe due to a watchOS update.
The reason is that the `activeComplications` property of the `CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()` is `nil`, although my complication placeholder is shown on the watch face (device & simulator).

The code could not be simpler:

```
final class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {
// …
    func updateComplications() {
//…
        let complicationServer = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
        if let activeComplications = complicationServer.activeComplications {
            for complication in activeComplications {
                complicationServer.reloadTimeline(for: complication)
            }
        }
//…
  }
//…
}
```

If I stop at a breakpoint at the `if let` instruction, `complicationServer` has the following values:

[image]

And the following lldb command outputs `nil`:
[image]

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad: [I solved the problem 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45494772/1987726), but forgot the solution during refactoring of the app.
Actually I don’t know if this is a solution, a workaround or a hack:

I suspect that the `CLKComplicationServer` or its `CLKComplicationDataSource`, i.e. the `ComplicationController`, is not correctly initialized if `ComplicationController.shared` is executed anywhere in the code. If not, the `ComplicationController` is correctly initialized by the `CLKComplicationServer`.

Therefore, one cannot call any function in the `ComplicationController`, e.g. to update complications. Instead one can send a notification to the `ComplicationController` that executes the requested function. Of course, one has to ensure that the `ComplicationController` is already initialized and registered to receive such a notification before it is posted.
If so, `CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance().activeComplications` is no longer `nil`, and the complication update works.